# Parâmetro pelo Ajax

Tags: ajax

Estou precisando passar alguns argumentos pelo Ajax, a princípio o código apresenta erro de sintaxe.

```
            var comeco = $("data_filtroe").val();
            var fim = $("data_filtrod").val();    
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "status_relatorio.php",
                data: "comeco="+comeco+" && fim="+fim,
                success: function(data){
                    document.querySelector('#status_dia').innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
```

Código PHP("status_relatorio.php"):

```
<?php 
session_start();
$con = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","eeep_#2017");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_select_db("alunos",$con);
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' ); 
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Fortaleza' );
$data_inicio = $_GET['comeco'];
$data_fim = $_GET['fim'];
$data="";
for ($i=$data_inicio; $i <= $data_fim; $i++) { 
    if($data==""){
        $data = "data = ".$i;
    }else{
        $data = "and data = ".$i;
    }
}
if($data_inicio==$data_fim){
$data = "data=".$data_inicio;
}
$sql = "select * from ocorrencias where '$data' order by curso, nome_aluno asc";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$cont = 0;
$falta = 0;
$falta_justificada = 0;
$fardamento_incompleto = 0;
$es_autorizada = 0;
$indis = 0;
while($linha1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $cont++;
    if($linha1['tipo']=="Falta"){
        $falta++;
    }
    if($linha1['tipo']=="Falta Justificada"){
        $falta_justificada++;
    }
    if($linha1['tipo']=="Fardamento Incompleto"){
        $fardamento_incompleto++;
    }
    if($linha1['tipo']=="Entrada/Saída Autorizada"){
        $es_autorizada++;
    }
    if($linha1['tipo']=="Indisciplína"){
        $indis++;
    }
}
        echo "<table cellpadding='3' id='status_dia'>
            <tr>
                <td class='status'>Faltas: <label>".$data_inicio."</label></td>
                <td class='status'>Faltas Justificadas: <label>".$falta_justificada."</label></td>
                <td class='status'>Fardamentos Incompletos: <label>".$fardamento_incompleto."</label></td>
                <td class='status'>Entradas/Saídas Autorizadas: <label>".$es_autorizada."</label></td>
                <td class='status'>Indisciplína: <label>".$indis."</label></td>
                <td class='status'>Total: <label>".$cont."</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>";?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Continuou sem dar certo. Erro : Notice: Undefined index: comeco in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema - Controle Geral de Alunos\status_relatorio.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: fim in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema - Controle Geral de Alunos\status_relatorio.php on line 12

Comment: Eu fiz isso... código de receber... $data_inicio = $_GET['comeco'];
 $data_fim = $_GET['fim'];

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Dá uma olhada na minha resposta e nos meus comentários nela. Utilize `$_POST["comeco"]`, `$_POST["fim"]`.

Comment: Outra coisa... Há inúmeros erros em seu código. O mais grave é que você está utilizando a extensão `mysql` que foi removida completamente no PHP 7 e depreciada  desde a versão 5.4 do mesmo.

Comment: Outra coisa... É bem mais fácil, simples, rápido e prático você realizar uma consulta separada da outra baseado no `tipo de falta que você quer`... Ou utilizar `COUNT()` e `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing Não posso usar a função group by, porque preciso mostrar exatamente todos os valores.

Comment: Como eu disse... Você pode utilizar `COUNT()` baseado no tipo que vc deseja e agrupá-los. Você tem 5 tipos diferentes, certo? É só você contar as linhas que possuem o `tipo X` e agrupar nesse tipo, contas as linhas que possem o `tipo Y` e agrupar. Dessa forma, o `SELECT` vai retornar apenas 5 linhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) você precisa enviar dados no formato *PlainObject*, *String* ou *Array*.

> data Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Escreva o código abaixo:

```
        // Supondo que "data_filtroe" é uma classe. 
        // Se for um ID, utilize $("#data_filtroe").val(); 
        var comeco = $(".data_filtroe").val();
        // Supondo que "data_filtrod" é uma classe.
        // Se for um ID, utilize $("#data_filtrod").val();    
        var fim = $(".data_filtrod").val();    
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "status_relatorio.php",
            data: { "comeco": comeco, "fim": fim },
            success: function(data){
                document.querySelector('#status_dia').innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
```

Lembrando que:

1. GET - Busca, requer, solicita dados de algum lugar especificado.
2. POST - Envia os dados para serem processados em algum lugar especificado.

Comment: Não deu certo, não apareceu nada.

Comment: `data: { "comeco": comeco, "fim": fim }` este trecho está enviado as duas variáveis para o script PHP `status_relatorio.php`. No PHP, você deverá recuperar as variáveis através de `$_POST["comeco"]` e `$_POST["fim"]`. E por fim, no seu arquivo PHP, para devolver algum tipo de informação para a requisição `Ajax`, você deve fazer `echo json_encode("Olá mundo, estou saindo do PHP e voltando ao JS");`

Comment: O código não retorna nada, quando uso esse código.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, dê uma olhada. E também poste o código PHP na sua pergunta.